# MacBook Pro 15" (Mid 2012) won't connect to a specific wifi network

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi

Recently installed fibre optic (in the UK) so have a new wifi router/network, and I cannot connect my MacBook Pro 15" Mid 2012.
I can still connect to my old wifi network on the MacBook Pro though.

The strange thing is I can connect to my new network on my phone and MacBook Air, as well as other devices.

Any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Do you mean (in your first sentence) that you _cannot_ connect my MacBook Pro 15" Mid 2012?"

Comment: yes sorry. I cannot connect my macbook pro to the new network. But I can connect it to my old network still.

Comment: Because your MacBook Pro can connect to your old network, we can presume the MacBook Pro's network hardware is OK. Because your MacBook Air can connect to the new network, we can presume the Air's settings are correct. Carefully review all the network settings in the Pro; you're likely to find the Pro is not set up the same as the Air. Duplicate the Air's network settings on the Pro.

Comment: how would I go about duplicating the network settings? would this be in /library or more in network on system preferences? appreciate the help

Comment: I have tried renaming the 2.4ghz and 5ghz to two separate networks and the MacBook Pro seemed to be able to connect to the 2.4ghz network but not the 5ghz network.

the old network would have been 2.4ghz and 5ghz though (and isn't split into two networks)

Comment: In the MacBook Pro, go to System Preferences > Network > Wifi > Advanced. Make sure the info entered in each tab (for example, "TCP/IP") is the same as on the MacBook Air.